# transformation of matrices which represents an eigenvalue problem within the same solution space.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

(A) For the two variable (two dimensional) system of coupled homogeneous ordinary differential equations (dX/dt = AX) say, (dy/dt)=5y+2x and (dx/dt)=3y+6x , express the original variables y & x in terms of transformed variables y' & x' (Transform vector X to vector X') through "suitable" linear combinations of "appropriate" basis vectors, such that Y' = (lambda) Y' represents an eigenvalue problem within the same solution space.

(B) Solve the transformed system of variables to obtain the solutions of y' & x'.

(C) Find the corresponding solutions for x & y and hence prove that the solution technique discussed in class belongs to the same solution space.

(D) Generalize the problem and frame it properly for an arbitrary two-variable coupled homogeneous ordinary differential equations (i.e. any general matrix A) and figure out the standard solution procedure based on above steps.

(E) Extend the 2-dimensional problem to a general n-dimensions and frame the problem. Solve it too (for the general case).

Comment: Paragraphs and [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting would make this much easier to read, and much more likely to get a positive reception.

Comment: Showing that you’ve put some effort into solving what looks like a homework problem will help even more.